# How can I get filtered data objects from AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

i have trouble to figure out how i can receive the filtered data after the change event took place. My code structure looks like the following. THe alert is fired but how to move on?

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body ng-controller="List">

    Search: <input ng-change="getData()" ng-model="query">
    Search: <select ng-change="getData()" ng-model="query2">
    <option></option>
    <option>Berlin</option>
    <option>Hamburg</option>
</select>
 <div>
    <ul class="names" >
        <li ng-model="item" " ng-repeat="name in names | filter:query | filter:query2">
            {{name.firstname}}, {{name.lastname}}, {{name.age}}, {{name.location}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function List($scope) {
        $scope.names = [
        {"firstname": "Carl",
        "lastname": "Luyk",
        "age": 20,
        "location":"Berlin"},
        {"firstname": "Carl",
        "lastname": "Moreen",
        "age": 20,
        "location":"Hamburg"},
        {"firstname": "Tom",
        "lastname": "Luyk",
        "age": 25,
        "location":"New York"},
        {"firstname": "Caren",
        "lastname": "Tilt",
        "age": 20,
    "location":"Paris"},
        {"firstname": "Caren",
        "lastname": "Orail",
        "age": 30,
        "location":"Hamburg"},
        ];
    $scope.getData= function(){
    //here I would like to get the data structured like $scope.names..is that possible?
    alert('changed');

    }

    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could filter the list in Javascript instead of using HTML template binding. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Comment: [This the most effective answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21509043/452708)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular js: Access data filtered in ng-repeat (ngRepeat) from controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499077/angular-js-access-data-filtered-in-ng-repeat-ngrepeat-from-controller)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Search: <input ng-change="getData(names, query)" ng-model="query">
```

And inside your Controller:

```
$scope.getData = function (names, query) {
  $scope.queryData = $filter('filter')(names, query));
};
```

So $scope.queryData is now your results collection.

Comment: thanks a lot...but it raises the error "$filter is undefined" any idea?

Comment: @Jurudocs not sure if you ever figured it out, but that is because you need to inject $filter into your controller.

Comment: This will throw a syntax error due to an unclosed parenthesis on line 2.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting "$filter is underfined" is because you haven't injected it into your controller. When you define your controller, do:

```
app.controller('list', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.getData = function (names, query) {
    $scope.queryData = $filter('filter')(names, query));
  };
}
```

You can also define your search in your controller.

```
$scope.queryData = $filter('filter')(array, search-expression));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: So will `search-expression` be equal to `query`?

Comment: `$filter('filter')(array, search-expression))` The extra closing bracket, is it a typo??

Comment: @UdaySawant Yeah, the fact it's in two answers is pretty sad. Downvoting until fixed!