# How Can I Access the Collection of Filtered Objects When Using AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS.  I have a table on my HTML page for which the rows are populated from an array of objects in the $scope using ng-repeat with a filter.  The filter is populated from an input box above the table.

If I want to add a button or some other UI object to the page that when clicked will perform some operation on the array of objects that are selected as a result of the filter, how can I obtain access to the filtered array from the javascript code in my controller?  Is there a way to apply the user-supplied filter to the array or to iterate over the filtered array?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $filter function directly in JavaScript inside the button click handler as such:

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

See [AngularJS documentation on $filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) (In JavaScript section) for more details.

Here's another similar question: [Accessing ng-repeat filtered data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499077/angular-js-access-data-filtered-in-ng-repeat-ngrepeat-from-controller)

Comment: Thanks, Sid.  That worked perfectly.  Sorry I missed the similar question in my search.